# ssl, silverlight, wcf and local install

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis, ssl, out-of-browser

I'm trying to get a silverlight program to install locally and still be able to access wcf data services over ssl. When I run the application in browser, everything works fine. When I run the application out of browser without ssl everything works fine. When I run the application OoB with ssl, I get a "Not Found" error. When I run fiddler and retry, everything works fine. I'm guessing that the program isn't correctly decrypting or sending the ssl traffic when OoB since when fiddler does it for it, the application works fine. I'm also not hitting any exceptions or break points on the server when I attach VS to it (this makes me think there is a problem with the send). Any ideas on what my next step should be? Also, I am using a self signed certificate, could this be an issue? THANKS!

Comment: I believe that SSL communication relies on the browser stack. Because you are no longer in the browser, there is no access to that stack and so, SLL does not work. I am not sure what would fix this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145759/silverlight-and-ssl-client-certificates

Not sure if this helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone found a resolution for this issue? Or does silverlight just not work with SSL in OOB mode??

See this link for reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295(v=vs.95).aspx

basically it says:

> Client certificates are supported by the browser stack, but not by the
>   client stack.  And there is currently an issue that (at least for our
>   application) prevents client certificates from working even with the
>   browser stack if you're in trusted out-of-browser mode.

Comment: Thanks, same issue here, if someone find a way, i'm interested too ^^