# Silverlight application SSL WCF Self hosted Service Works in browser but not out of browser

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, service, out-of-browser

[ssl, silverlight, wcf and local install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408483/ssl-silverlight-wcf-and-local-install)

I am having this exact same problem but I cannot find a resolution to it?.. Anyone have any ideas??

My app works fine in browser, but not out of browser. I'm using a self hosted WCF service over SSL (using a self generated SSL Cert). If I run the app out of browser with fiddler running, it works. Without fiddler, it doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ssl, silverlight, wcf and local install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408483/ssl-silverlight-wcf-and-local-install)

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate...??? That post wasnt answered but I'm having the same exact issue..

Comment: @user587950: The lack of an answer does not mean the question isn't a duplicate. You stated that you are having "the exact same problem". By definition, that means this is a duplicate. I understand the frustration in not solving the problem, but consider upvoting the other question or placing a bounty on it to encourage others to help answer it.

Comment: The symptom "works with Fiddler running, but not if Fiddler is not running", translates to "works when an Internet proxy is being used for all requests, but not if an Internet proxy is not being used". Usually this means that you are not using a proxy to access your service, and that you _should_ be using a proxy.