# Silverlight client HTTP stack vs browser HTTP stack

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, ssl, out-of-browser

I have a silverlight application I am using to connect to a SSL WCF service and it is working in the web browser but not in OOB(out of browser) mode.

I found another post related to this that said OOB mode does not support SSL certificates because the client http stack is different from the browser http stack.

Can anyone explain the differences or validate that this is not supported in silverlight?

I cannot find anything from Microsoft regarding the issue; however, I have seen several other posts in other forums with similar issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the other stack overflow post i found that is related to this question:

[Silverlight and SSL Client Certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145759/silverlight-and-ssl-client-certificates)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I found this url from ms : 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295(v=vs.95).aspx

Client certificates are supported by the browser stack, but not by the client stack.  And there is currently an issue that (at least for our application) prevents client certificates from working even with the browser stack if you're in trusted out-of-browser mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this url from ms : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295(v=vs.95).aspx

Client certificates are supported by the browser stack, but not by the client stack. And there is currently an issue that (at least for our application) prevents client certificates from working even with the browser stack if you're in trusted out-of-browser mode.